# Horizontal hexagonal chains (chemfig/tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I am using LaTeX for research with hexagonal chains and would like to know some ways to create a horizontal hexagonal chain.

Is it possible to use `chemfig` or `tikz` to create a chain similar to either of these please?

[image: chain with dotted line]

[image: chain with 3 hexagons]

Comment: I've found the following library useful: https://github.com/mossblaser/tikz-hexagon

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74607964/latex-hexagonal-chains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to connect hex rings. Note that the additional rings only have 5 "-" (bonds), the sixth bond is common between the two rings.

See section 12.4 of the chemfig manual

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(-----)---)----)}
\end{document}
```

[image]